# Why am I getting all this space at runtime (emulator/device) when the previews show exactly what I expect them to look like? Nevermind (but read on!)

Tags: android

[Android-studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pONII.jpg)
(TLDR: yes, it shows exactly what I want to see BUT it's not what I expected to be running. The xml it's only the "row" layout. It gets used by another xml which, yes: bloody 16dp for the outter layout + another 16dp for the recycler view, both in the item_list.xml)

The screenshot features:

- Leftmost: layout for list row
- middle: the layout showing correct margins/padding
- rightmost: emulator showing the huge space between border and left Textview.

Can anybody shed some light on this? It's finally taking it's toll on my patience after
weeks of reading (both a book and replies to similar questions). As you may have guessed by now, it all turned out to be but a futile exercise.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Ideally you should have added your XML/code in your question in addition to an image. Have you tried the layout inspector: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector to identify where your margins & padding are coming from?

Comment: You should share enough details that someone else could replicate this. If I had to guess,  I'd guess your main layout has some start/end margin or padding that is added to the margin in your row layout.